# Include a single header from a different directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have a small build in which I want to include only a single header file (and source file) from a different directory. I know how to use the -I parameter, but do not want to include the entire directory, only the individual files.

My makefile looks like this:

```
myproj: ui.o data.o string.o
    c99 -ggdb -o myproj ui.o data.o string.o
    ctags *

ui.o : ui.c data.h
    c99 -ggdb -c ui.c

data.o : data.c data.h
    c99 -ggdb -c data.c

string.o : ../../shared/src/string.c ../../shared/src/string.h
    c99 -ggdb -c ../../shared/src/string.c ../../shared/src/string.h -o ./jcstring.o
```

When I try to make it complains that `string.h` is not found:

```
c99 -ggdb -c ui.c ../../shared/src/string.h
In file included from ui.c:7:0:
data.h:1:22: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
 #include "string.h"
```

How can I include this file without including the whole directory?

Comment: Early in the 'make' file generate the list of source files, perhaps by ``SRC := $( wildcard *.c )`  and the list of object files, perhaps by `OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)`

Comment: change the default header file search path, which is an entry in the environment, to include the directory-path to the desired file. Also note that your 'make' file would be MUCH better is it included the necessary statements to produce the 'dependency' file for each source file Then the recipe to produce the string.o (best to not change the root name in mid stride) would look similar to: %.o : %.c %d followed on the next line similar to: <tab>c99 -ggdb -c $< -o $@ -I. toward the end of the 'make' file need to add the statements: `ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif`

Comment: early in the 'make' file include a statement similar to: `CCFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu99`

Comment: Note: the `$(DEP)` macro would be generated similar to: `DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)`

Answer (score 5):

> I know how to use the -I parameter, but do not want to include the entire directory, only the individual files.

`-I` doesn't “include a directory”, it just puts the directory on the search path. It doesn't matter that the directory contains other files that you don't want. The only files that the compiler will read are the ones whose name is in an `#include` directive. So if you have a `../../shared/src/string.h` then you can use the following compilation command:

```
c99 -ggdb -I ../../shared/src -c ui.c
```

In the case of `string.`, the header is in the same directory as the source file. This is where the compiler will look first, so you don't need `-I` at all.

```
c99 -ggdb -c ../../shared/src/string.c -o ./jcstring.o
```

The only scenario in which adding `-I` options can hurt is if there are header files with the same name in different directories. For example, if all four of the following files exist:

```
one/foo.h
one/bar.h
two/foo.h
two/bar.h
```

and you want to compile code containing

```
#include "foo.h" /* must refer to one/foo.h */
#include "bar.h" /* must refer to two/bar.h */
```

then you can't do it with just `-I` directives. Either you put `-I one` first and `#include "bar.h"` will include `one/bar.h`, or you put `-I two` first and `#include "foo.h"` will include `two/foo.h`. The sane solution is to not run into this problem. Headers inside the same project should have unique names. If you're including headers from different projects then you should include the project name in the include directives.

```
#include "one/foo.h"
#include "two/bar.h"
```

In principle you could copy one of the header files to a separate directory and include that, but in this situation, given typical naming conventions you're likely to run into name collisions between the projects.

Note also that `string.h` is not a good name for a header because it's the name of a standard library header. The compiler won't confuse the two in your case: `#include "string.h"` looks for the header file in the current directory if there is one, whereas `#include <string.h>` only looks in directories specified with `-I` and falls back to the standard library. Collisions with headers installed system-wide can happen, and it works as long as you don't mistype a file name, but it's confusing for humans to use a very well-known header name that is used in most projects.